# How to remove view when the view disappears for memory management?

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, view, uiview

In my project I have used the XIB file for all Views and initialise in the view controller. In one of the Viewcontroller I have using the GIF animation for instruct the user to follow steps. When this InstructionViewController page loads the memory gets increased as 100MB and when I click back and navigate to same screen it increase to 200MB.   I have tried the below steps to decrease the memory:

```
weak var instructionView:InstructionView? = nil
```

ViewDidLoad:

```
 instructionView = InstructionView().loadNib() as? InstructionView
```

viewDidDisappear:

```
instructionView?.removeFromSuperView()
```

But when i navigate from the instruction to another screen We have option to back to the navigation screen. In this case when i click the back button the view is appeard with white screen because of removeFromSuperView.

**Note:**
 I have tried to move the viewdidLoad code to viewwillappear but the memory is not decreased?

Is any other way to decrease the memory and also the appear the instruction screen without issue?

Comment: Some time ago I tried to show a number of GIFs in the TableView, and both memory consumption and performance were unacceptable. In the end, I decided to load the assets converted from GIF to MP4 (the API provided such an option) and display them with AVPlayer, and it worked like a charm. Also, MP4 files were significantly smaller in size than GIF. Consider this as another viable option

Comment: Thanks @ArtemGarmash. It's really helpful

Comment: It seem to be you havd memory leak, please read about ARC and retain cycle